# Errors creating a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Whenever I try to create a string in my header file I get the error: 'string' is not a member of 'std'. I am using the Microsoft Visual c++ express 2010 compiler. Here is my header file:

```
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
 string name;
 string p_number;

public:
 Person();
 Person(string, string);
 string get_number();
 string get_name();
};
```

I am a decent java programmer who just started  learning c++

Comment: @Tom: you should have added that as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Do you also have `#include <string>` in your header?  You need it for the declarations of the string classes.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Why don't I need #include <string> in my main file? The only thing my main file includes in <iostream>

Comment: @Daniel: If your main file is including your header file, you are effectively including `<string>` in the main file too.

Comment: @Daniel: In C++, standard headers are allowed (but not required) to include other standard headers. So if your main file includes `<iostream>`, it's presumably getting `<string>` too because your implementation happens to have a dependency there.

Comment: @Daniel: Based off of what Steve and Niall said, you must remember your program's structure and hierarchy. E.g. <iostream> is included in something.h and something.h is included in main.cpp but not something_else.cpp. Then iostream is effectively included in any file where something.h is included (in this case main.cpp) and not those files which do not (in this case something_else.cpp). So if you had no reason to include something.h into something_else.cpp, you would simply re-include <iostream> if you needed the standard functionality in there as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You must include the string file like this:

```
#include <string>
```

to use `std::string` .

It's something like import in Java, except that Java imports classes / namespaces, C++ imports libraries or header files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
#include <string>
```

at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
using std::string;
```

will not include unnecessary declarations and definitions present in `string` header and will be helpful only for compiler's lookup and would compile fine, I usually prefer following instead of including whole header files:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

*For example purpose only.